# What is the best and safest option for installing software that is not part of the distribution's official sources?

Tags: debian, software-installation, flatpak

I used to run Linux in VMs in the past and I was pretty careless on what I installed.
But I have installed Debian lately as my first bare-metal Linux system and I've read that Debian's outstanding stability can be affected when installing things that are outside their official sources:
https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

I was a bit heartbroken by this, since many software packages that I wanted installed are not in the official sources and, even when there is a flatpak available, it seems that they don't work flawlessly or their functionality is hindered by the sandboxing technology used.

Specifically, I was planning to install VS Code, Powershell, and .NET, but they don't seem to exist in the official repositories (for the 3rd there might be an alternative with Mono, but I don't think it is quite the same). I've tried installing VS Code from Flathub, but the installation came with a warning that:

> This version is running inside a container and is therefore not able
> to access SDKs on your host system!

Also, running flatpaks outside a sandbox seems not supported and there doesn't seem to be any flatpak or apt package for powershell or .NET.

So, which is my best option?

1. Shall I install this software directly into the OS, despite the fact that might alter some library version that may lead to problems?
2. Shall I try making things work with flatpaks, no matter how unlikely this seems?
3. Maybe I should try snaps, that seem to allow installing without a sandbox, and despite the fact the Debian community/authors lean towards flatpaks?
4. Maybe try some virtualization technology again (e.g. running another Linux distro in a VirtualBox VM and not care for it being destroyed)?

And another question:

Why is this software (.NET, PowerShell, VS Code, etc) not part of the official repositories? From what I know they are open source. Are there some licensing incompatibilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET and VS Code are provided in `apt` repositories by Microsoft; see [the installation instructions for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) and [those for .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian). PowerShell is available for Debian 9 and 10, but not yet 11; see [the corresponding installation instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/install-debian?view=powershell-7.2).

The main risks associated with repositories are two-fold:

1. Non-official repositories might provide packages which don’t match your system’s; this is the kind of setup described as FrankenDebian, and isn’t a problem here (Microsoft provide repositories specifically matched to different Debian releases).
2. Non-official repositories might not be trustworthy. In this case, since you already trust Microsoft by running their software, the risk isn’t greater if you also use their repositories. Their can be a trustworthiness risk related to the possibility that a repository could be hijacked, but this seems low to me in this case too.

You can also use `apt` pinning to make absolutely sure that only those packages you want to install are actually installed from a third-party repository; see [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration#apt_preferences_.28APT_pinning.29) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the information! I ended up using a mix of snaps and MS repositories. I cannot say that I trust MS much (although I do trust them more than Google, Facebook and the rest...), but since I am a developer and I know .NET well enough to perform every simple task by running code, I would probably feel constrained inside a Linux system, if it was not running some form of .NET. Although, C++ and Qt is something I could work with too.

Answer (score 1):

If you worry about the interaction of vscode with your Debian system, a Snap installation may be the right way to proceed :

https://wiki.debian.org/VisualStudioCode

`sudo snap install powershell --classic`

https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap

Comment: Thanks, I tried snaps and they seem more flexible than flatpaks, although the integration with Debian and Xfce seems a bit problematic. But nothing came up that cannot be fixed so far...